# Publishing a remote GIT repository on the same server

Tags: git

Sorry for the dumb question, but I haven't managed to understand how.
I have a local repo and a remote repo on the server, both are Ubuntu. I'ts all okay, commits work over SSH, but how do I force the remote server into publishing the repo into /var/www ?

Comment: @AzizShaikh: I was aware of GIT hooks (I've tried already post-receive). I suspect after some research that the problem is that my repository is a bare one, maybe a non-bare is the correct way to go.

Comment: If your web server and git server (remote) are different machines then on the web server you should have a bare repo.

Comment: @AzizShaikh: no, web server and remote are on the same machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem:

1. I configured the local repository
2. I created a bare repository on the remote server

   git init --bare
3. I've taken the necessary steps to configure committing to the remote repo
4. I added a **post-receive** hook under the *hooks* folder of my remote repository

**/path/to/repo/hooks/post-receive**:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/www.example.org git checkout -f
```

Then I `chmod`-ded it:

```
chmod +x /path/to/repo/hooks/post-receive
```